# git push unexpected behavior with 2 remotes

Tags: git

I have the following setup:

remotes:

origin, vijay

local branches:

- master
- 14.4_dev (created by doing git checkout origin/14.4_dev -b 14.4_dev)
- 14.4_various_features (created by doing checkout vijay/14.4_various_features -b 14.4_various_features)

When I am on the 14.4_various_features branch and do git push, it pushes my local branches (such as master and 14.4_dev) into the vijay remote. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [documentation of the `push.default` option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) on how to change the behavior when running just `git push`:

> **push.default**
>
> Defines the action `git push` should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what you want. Possible values are:
>
> - `nothing` - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
> - `current` - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
> - `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.
>
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.
> - `matching` - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed there).
>
>   To use this mode effectively, you have to make sure all the branches you would push out are ready to be pushed out before running git push, as the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the branches in one go. If you usually finish work on only one branch and push out the result, while other branches are unfinished, this mode is not for you. Also this mode is not suitable for pushing into a shared central repository, as other people may add new branches there, or update the tip of existing branches outside your control.

Most likely it's currently set to `matching` while you'd prefer `simple` or upstream`.

Comment: thanks for this. It was indeed matching. I don't mind this behavior as long as I know what it is doing now.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.git/config` file you can choose which one is the default remote for each branch. At this point, it probably says

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = vijay
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "14.4_various_features"]
        remote = vijay
        merge = refs/heads/14.4_various_features
[branch "14.4_dev"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/14.4_dev
```

Depending on your global git push strategy, your pushes might do what you're describing. Unless your strategy is set to 'current' git will iterate over your branches pushing each one of them to their matching branch in their respective remotes.

Answer (score 0):

> and do git push

That means "without refspec given".
On that point, with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), do note the removal of the "`explicitly`" term.

See [commit 8b2a192](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b2a1928f08a0c795de1a84aa329bc85dcdb3949) (29 Jan 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4cf7f48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cf7f48891d36d9ec3783119ddc1177fa9f0581e), 12 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b2a1928f08a0c795de1a84aa329bc85dcdb3949): drop "explicitly given" from push.default description
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> The documentation for `push.default` mentions that it is used if no refspec is "explicitly given".
>   Let's drop the notion of "explicit" here, since it's vague, and just mention that any refspec from anywhere is sufficient to override this.
>
> I've dropped the mention of "explicitly given" from the definition of the "nothing" value right below, too. It's close enough to our clarification that it should be obvious we mean the same type of "given" here.

As [Junio C. Hamano explained](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqr1zj6xl6.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/):

> I am not sure the act of deliberately setting `remote.*.push` configuration should not count as an explicit request to Git the user makes.
>
> Immediately follows the above, the description of one of the possible values read thusly:
>
> > - `nothing` - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given.
> >       This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
>
> which may need an adjustment to keep the whole coherent.
>   If we decide to say that setting configuration does not count as explicit,
>   then "unless a refspec is explicitly given" should be updated to
>   match.
>   There may be other mention of "explicitly" that needs to be adjusted (I didn't hunt for it, but the above one was adjacent and I couldn't not see it).
>
> If we have to change anything in the description, I would say that we can just drop "explicitly".
>   There are ways to give refspec from the command line, `remote.*.push` configuration, in `.git/remotes` file, etc.
>   If it were "if you give refspec from command line, X happens, but giving a config-sourced refspec does not cause X to happen", that may be a good reason to invent and use a new phrase "implicitly given" that is not used in this paragraph.
>   But `push.default` kicks in only when *none* of these ways is used to give *any* refspec, so there is not much point differenciating between the command line sourced refspec and config sourced refspec in the context of discussing this feature, I would think.